# Error in dictionary replace function "more elements supplied than there are to replace"

Tags: r

I'm translating text in a dataset from one language to another. I have a dictionary for that language.

Here's how the dictionary (dict) looks.

> id  Lang  English
>
> 1   Juu   Up
>
> 2   Chini Down

The dictionary contains 365 rows and 3 columns. My data has 3000+ rows and ~100 columns.

Here's my code:

```
translated <- vector("double", ncol(dataset))  
for (i in seq_along(dataset)) {            
 # dict[match(dataset[[i]], dict$Lang), 2, drop=F]
  translated[[i]] <- with(dict, English[match(dataset[[i]], Lang)])      
}
tr_dataset <- as.data.frame(translated)
```

Here's the error I keep getting
Error in output[[i]] <- with(dict, English[match(b[[i]], Lang)]) : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `with()` in programming. Here is what the documentation says:

For interactive use this is very effective and nice to read. For programming however, i.e., in one's functions, more care is needed, and typically one should refrain from using with(), as, e.g., variables in data may accidentally override local variables, see the reference.

I cannot test the approach because you did not provide a [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but this may work:

```
translated <- vector("double", ncol(dataset))  
for (i in seq_along(dataset)) {            
 # dict[match(dataset[[i]], dict$Lang), 2, drop=F]
  translated[[i]] <- dict$English[match(dataset[[i]], Lang)]) # this row changed    
}
tr_dataset <- as.data.frame(translated)
```